# AAD login - delegate permission to filesystem

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-active-directory, active-directory, filesystems

#### What I have

1. The Windows Server connected to AD, which is sychronized with AAD somehow
2. Documents stored on filesystem (shared network folder). There are various security rules applied to the documents - more or less a subfolder per security group. Not all users can read all documents.
3. Asp.net core (.NET 7) app that uses AAD single sign on (Microsoft Identity Platfrom). It reads the documents and show it to the user.

Currently the app has access to all documents.

#### What I need

User should not be able to read all documents, only those where he has access to.

#### Question

Is it somehow possible to delegate the permissions when accessing filesystem when using AAD single sign on?